# Sonar PAM authentication

Tags: debian, sonarqube, pam

I am trying to set up Sonar to use PAM authentication. I have followed the installation instructions fron the [docs](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PAM+Plugin), but I can't get it to work. From the sonar.log file I get

ERROR o.s.p.p.PamConfiguration  Unable to determine PAM service name. Please check that 'pam.serviceName' property is set in 'sonar.properties' in

ERROR rails  Error from external authenticator: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

It seems that it can't locate the JPam library or something. I tried setting sonar.properties to JPam in sonar.properties, but it does not seem like the right name as I get the error:

ERROR rails  Error from external authenticator: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory

in the log. If anyone has any pointers as to where to go from here I would be most grateful.

Comment: You should try to ping Marco Tizzoni which is the author of this plugin as there aren't so many known users of this Sonar plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must set the property `pam.serviceName` in `sonar.properties` as stated in the log.

```
pam.serviceName=system-auth
```

You could replace `system-auth` with any PAM service, i.e. those listed in `/etc/pam.d/`.

Unfortunately this row went lost somehow in the docs for the version 0.2 I am gonna update the wiki. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. I tried setting pam.serviceName to net-sf-jpam, which is bundled with JPAM. The log now says "Error from external authenticator: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory". Any ideas?

Comment: commons-logging.jar is not used by the plugin but by JPAMYou must ensure the appropriate jar is in the classpath. Please follow the instructions for installing JPAM as mentioned in the docs.